# writing into .csv-file inside of "while"-loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, while-loop

By using

```
result = open("data/"+ name + "_" + timestamp + ".csv", "w")
result.write("time; data1; data2; data3 \n")`
```

I open a file and fill it with the column identifiers.

Using

```
while True:
    timestamp = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    data1,data2,data3 = device.fetchData()

    result.write(timestamp +";"+ str(data1) +";"+ str(data1) +";"+ str(data3) +"\n")
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

the .csv-file should be filled with measuring data. The problem now is, that if I check the file after exiting the script, it's **completely empty**, not even the column identifiers are present.
However, if I use a for-loop, it works like it should.

Very strange for my understanding.

Comment: Did you close the file object at the end? `result.close()`

Comment: You haven't shown the version with the `for` loop so it's hard to guess. Also it's unclear what `fetchData` does. Try to create a minimal example that shows the issue, without dependencies to other parts of your project.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to leave this program running indefinitely to collect data from some kind of sensor, and so I suspect the issue is the default buffering from your [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) call.

Firstly, you should almost always be using a "with" block like @Spirine suggests, but in your case a slight modification is in order:

```
with open("data/"+ name + "_" + timestamp + ".csv", "w", 1) as result:
```

The `, 1` at the end indicates line buffering, meaning that Python will write the file to disk at the end of each line. Also, consider using str.format() to make it a bit more polished:

```
log_line_template = "{ts:%H:%M:%S};{d1};{d2};{d3}\n"
filename = "data/{n}_{ts:%H_%M_%S}.csv".format(n=name, ts=datetime.now())

with open(filename, "w", 1) as result:
    result.write("time; data1; data2; data3 \n")`

    while True:
        data1,data2,data3 = device.fetchData()
        result.write(log_line_template.format(
            ts=datetime.now(), data1, data2, data3
        ))
        time.sleep(seconds)
```

Comment: Ok, that sounded good until i tried it out and: Same result as before:( The file is empty.
I didnt't use the formatting stuff, as i don't understand it yet, but this shouldn't stop it from working.
I run the script inside the eclipse environment and stop it with the stop-button.

Comment: A colleague gave me solution:

Comment: A colleague gave me the solution:
Inside the loop there has to be a result.flush() to write the data to the disk.
Can you explain, why the ",1" has no effect?

Comment: Weird weird weird. I didn't really try this before posting the answer,  but I did some experiments after the fact. Here's what I found: a simplified version of the code I showed you does not write to the file, as you saw. This is with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Changing the buffering value to a number  > 1 does work, no `flush()` needed. **If I separate out the "\n" and do a `write("\n")` by itself, the `1` value works as expected.**

I think this is a Python bug.

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn't correctly written it's because you're program is incorrectly stopped: to escape of the while loop, what do you do ?
If you don't want to modify your code too much, you could just use the `open` context manager:

```
with open("data/"+ name + "_" + timestamp + ".csv", "w") as result:
    result.write("time; data1; data2; data3 \n")`

    while True:
        timestamp = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        data1,data2,data3 = device.fetchData()

        result.write(timestamp +";"+ str(data1) +";"+ str(data1) +";"+ str(data3) +"\n")
        time.sleep(seconds)
```

As it, no matter what happens, your file will be correctly closed in the end of your program.